# Date ranges in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

After fighting with NumPy and dateutil for days, I recently discovered the amazing Pandas library. I've been poring through the documentation and source code, but I can't figure out how to get `date_range()` to generate indices at the right breakpoints.

```
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd

start = date('2012-01-15')
end = date('2012-09-20')
# 'M' is month-end, instead I need same-day-of-month
date_range(start, end, freq='M')
```

What I want:

```
2012-01-15
2012-02-15
2012-03-15
...
2012-09-15
```

What I get:

```
2012-01-31
2012-02-29
2012-03-31
...
2012-08-31
```

I need month-sized chunks that account for the variable number of days in a month. This is possible with dateutil.rrule:

```
rrule(freq=MONTHLY, dtstart=start, bymonthday=(start.day, -1), bysetpos=1)
```

Ugly and illegible, but it works. How can do I this with pandas? I've played with both `date_range()` and `period_range()`, so far with no luck.

My actual goal is to use `groupby`, `crosstab` and/or `resample` to calculate values for each period based on sums/means/etc of individual entries within the period. In other words, I want to transform data from:

```
                total
2012-01-10 00:01    50
2012-01-15 01:01    55
2012-03-11 00:01    60
2012-04-28 00:01    80

#Hypothetical usage
dataframe.resample('total', how='sum', freq='M', start='2012-01-09', end='2012-04-15')
```

to

```
                total
2012-01-09          105 # Values summed
2012-02-09          0   # Missing from dataframe
2012-03-09          60
2012-04-09          0   # Data past end date, not counted
```

Given that Pandas originated as a financial analysis tool, I'm virtually certain that there's a simple and fast way to do this. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 24):

`freq='M'` is for month-end frequencies (see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)). But you can use `.shift` to shift it by any number of days (or any frequency for that matter):

```
pd.date_range(start, end, freq='M').shift(15, freq=pd.datetools.day)
```

Comment: Thanks, this may be the trick I need to create a solution based on the rrule hack. However, this doesn't help with resampling on a range, as resample will still use bins aligned to the beginning of the month AFAIK.

Comment: If you are going to shift by a consistent number of days it makes more sense to use month start 'MS': 
`pd.date_range(start, end, freq='MS').shift(15, freq=pd.datetools.day)`

Answer (score 9):

There actually is no "day of month" frequency (e.g. "DOMXX" like "DOM09"), but I don't see any reason not to add one.

http://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2289

I don't have a simple workaround for you at the moment because `resample` requires passing a known frequency rule. I think it should be augmented to be able to take any date range to be used as arbitrary bin edges, also. Just a matter of time and hacking...

Comment: This question just hit 10K views. Perhaps it's time to revisit this functionality?

Answer (score 9):

try

```
date_range(start, end, freq=pd.DateOffset(months=1))
```

Comment: For 'freq=...' one could also use pd.DateOffset(months=1)